# Is the following true: A is a proper subset of B implies A is strictly dominated by B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For A to be strictly dominated by B, there must exist an injection f: A to B and no bijection g: A to B.

Greetings. My exam’s just about an hour away and I would really appreciate much help. I remember that the statement is false but am  having a problem thinking of a mapping that would give a bijective function if A is a proper subset of B. Or is this the correct way to prove that the statement is false?

Thank you for whoever helps.

Comment: No. Consider any countably infinite set..

Comment: If $A=B$, then too $A$ is a subset of $B$ and the identity map is bijective. In case of strict containment, look for infinite countable sets, e.g. $A=\mathbb{N}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Infinite sets provide a counterexample.  In fact,  one definition of an infinite set is as a set that is in bijective correspondence with a proper subset.

Consider $\Bbb N$ and the subset $\Bbb N\setminus \{1\}$, say.  There is a bijection between these two sets.

For the bijection,  just shift by $1$.  This is sometimes referred to as "Hilbert's hotel".

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}-\{1\} \subset \mathbb{N}$
And $f:\mathbb{N}-\{1\} \to \mathbb{N}$

$f(n) = n-1$ is a bijection